# Can not deploy nodejs to heroku via heroku-cli and github

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I have an issue while deploy my nodejs Apps to Heroku. I tried to git push directly (heroku cli) and also tried from github deploy, but both of them failed. Here log i got:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
jq: error (at <stdin>:19): Cannot index string with string "iojs"
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

I tried to check maybe dev dependents was the culprit, then try to change dev dependents package and remove all node_modules filder which "may" cause failure, but after retry, I'm still faced this issue. Also I tried to change the engine from 17.x to 16.x but still persists.

Maybe someone can give me a clue?

Below package.json i have:

```
{
  "name": "coupling",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": "17.x",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@vercel/node": "^1.12.1",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "express": "4.17.2",
    "ws": "^8.4.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `engines` section is invalid:

```json
  "engines": "17.x",
```

[Its value should be an *object*, not a string](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#engines). Try this instead:

```json
  "engines": {
    "node": "17.x"
  }
```

Comment: I've editted but problem still persist. Checked on csv-parser there is text required iojs. So i use another module and use template from nodejs-getting-started and i successful deploy.

Comment: @fadlim, well the exact contents depend on your specific needs. I don't know anything about your application so you may have to. The point is that `engines` needs to be an _object_. That resolves the issue you were facing above. If you want to use io.js [you can](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/595), but that has nothing to do with the question you asked. (`iojs` is mentioned in the error, but that is just because it happens to be the first engine string that gets tried. The issue is that `jq` cannot process `"17.x"` as a JSON string.)

Comment: You mention the `node-js-getting-started` project. [It does exactly what I said in this answer, just with an older version of node](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/blob/15b9ad2f2fb7e8cc67bb29cc469171d201688f59/package.json#L5-L7).